# jquery php long polling request issue

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, long-polling

I'm making a chat which is based on long polling (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code/) )with PHP and jQuery. once whole page is downloaded in browser, a function makes a long polling request to the back-end with some timeout limit, when data comes from back-end it again makes the long-polling request and if any error, it will again make new long-polling request.

Problem : analyzing the traces by firebug, I've noticed that some times the long polling request is running 3 or 4 times, however it should not. there should only one long-polling request running per page.

however the code works perfectly. but long-polling request duplication is the issue.

```
function listen_for_message(){ 
// this functions is makes the long-polling request
$.ajax({
  url: "listen.php",
  timeout:5000,
  success: function(data) {
            $('#display').html(data);
            listen_for_message();
             }
  error: function() {
            setTimeOut("listen_for_message()",2000); // if error then call the function after 2 sec
  }
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please could you post your code which initiates the long polling?

Comment: edited the question, code included in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [terminate requests manualy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery):

```
var connection;
function longpoll() {
   if(connection != undefined) {
      connection.abort();
   }

   connection = $.ajax({ 
       ...
       complete: function() {
          longpool();
       }
   });
}
```

It may also be a Firefox/firebug issue (showing aborted connections as running), test it in Chrome.

UPDATE:

"In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period."
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: is there any way to do in code such that the code will check that if there is running a request then the function will returned else the function will called ?

Comment: You may use _connection_ variable as a flag to check if any ajax request is running and if so not allow to create a new one. Just set `connection = undefined;` in `complete` function and `return` at the beginning of `longpoll` function if `connection != undefined`.

Comment: yes you are right. this is a firebug / firefox issue, chrome doesnt show multiple pending requests. thanks for your suggestion. saved my time :)